# A non-numeric value is encountered - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller as below, i call the function `generate` which is found in my `model`.

When the function runs, it throws an error saying

> > A non-numeric value is encountered.

This error seems to be found in the function  `$chromosomes[] = is_numeric($gene['code']);`

So i used `is_numeric` to convert to numeric.

Why is this still happening? Thank you

**Controller**

```
 $timeTable = $timeTable->generate($condition['class']);
```

**Model**

```
public function generate($class)
    {
        $this->is_general = $class;
        if (!$this->slotsAreEnough()) {
            abort(500, 'The number of units exceed the available spaces.');
        }
         $this->makeChromosomes();
         $this->createInitialGeneration();
        $this->startSelection();
        return $this->timeTable;
    }


 private function makeChromosomes()
    {
        $chromosomes = array();
        foreach ($this->gene as $gene) {
            for ($x = 0; $x < $gene['units']; $x++) {
                $chromosomes[] = is_numeric($gene['code']);
            }
        }
        $this->chromosomes = $chromosomes;
        return $this;
    }

    private function startSelection()
    {
        $totalSlot = $this->daysOfWeek * $this->sizeOfDay;
        $size = count($this->chromosomes);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++) {
            $seed = rand(1, $totalSlot);
            for ($y = 0; $y < $this->daysOfWeek; $y++) {
                for ($z = 0; $z < $this->sizeOfDay; $z++) {
                    if ($this->hasAssigned($seed)) continue;
                    if ($this->isBreakTimeZone($seed)) continue;
                    $row = (int) ($seed / $this->sizeOfDay);
                    $col = $seed % $this->sizeOfDay;
                    if ($this->hasLevelWideCourses() && $this->levelWideCourses[$row][$col] != '-') {
                        $this->timeTable[$row][$col] = $this->levelWideCourses[$row][$col];
                    } else {
                        $this->timeTable[$row][$col] = $this->chromosomes[$x];
                    }
                    if (isset($this->chromosomes[$x + 1])){
                        if ($this->chromosomes[$x + 1] === $this->chromosomes[$x] && !$this->hasUsedDoublePeriods($this->chromosomes[$x])) {
                            $this->timeTable[$row][$col + 1] = $this->chromosomes[$x];
                            $this->hasDoublePeriod[] = $this->chromosomes[$x];
                        }
                    }
                    $this->usedSlots[] = $seed;
                    $this->selectVenue($this->chromosomes[$x], $row, $col);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: `is_numeric` does not convert to numeric, it returns a boolean if it is numeric.

Comment: @apokryfos, any function to help me convert to numeric?

Answer (score 2):

You want to change

`$chromosomes[] = is_numeric($gene['code']);`

to

`$chromosomes[] = (int)($gene['code']);`

or maybe

`$chromosomes[] = (float)($gene['code']);`

Comment: `float` is probably better since integers are included in floats but not the other way around

Comment: You can use `$chromosomes[] = intval($gene['code']);` It will convert the numbers in string into integer format. So when you use is_numeric it will return true for numbers inside strings, I mean in double or single quotes.